# How to fetch subgraph in neo4j such that the relationship's weight satisfy a comparison condition?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Imagine I have a huge graph. All the relationships have this numerical property called 'weight'. I want to fetch a subgraph comprised of a specified central node (by id) and its neighbors connected to it by relationships with weight greater than, say, 0.9.

I was trying to use APOC, but apparently, there is not an out-of-the-box option to establish a condition on the relationships.

```
MATCH (n:Assay {assay_id: "9995-6"})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, {
    relationshipFilter: "LINK",
    minLevel: 1,
    maxLevel: 1
})
YIELD nodes
RETURN node,n, LIMIT 25
```

For example, I would want to add a line like so:

```
MATCH (n:Assay {assay_id: "9995-6"})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, {
    relationshipFilter: "LINK",
    minLevel: 1,
    maxLevel: 1,
    r.weight > 0.9    #this line

})
YIELD nodes
RETURN node,n, LIMIT 25
```

But of course, that does not work. I hope there is a straightforward solution to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the relationships after you get the subgraph. Line 8 below with filter those relationships with wt > .9. Just ignore the visualization of the subgraph in the browser since this query is a some sort of a hack.

```
MATCH (n:Assay {assay_id: "9995-6"})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, {
    relationshipFilter: "LINK",
    minLevel: 1,
    maxLevel: 1
})
YIELD nodes, relationships  
WITH nodes, [r in relationships where r.wt > .9|r] as relationships
RETURN nodes, relationships LIMIT 25
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is there a way to prevent the now unconnected nodes from being returned?

Comment: And with "connected", I meant: "connected to the central node (i.e., 9995-6) by any number of hops"